# WebSocket error for WhatsApp Web on Chrome on OSX

Tags: macos, google-chrome, whatsapp, websocket

I am using Google Chrome on Mac OS X, and for the past day I cannot connect to WhatsApp Web

This is the error that I see in the Chrome Developer Console

[image: WhatsApp Web error messages]

I do not see anything that is blocking connection to http://*.web.whatsapp.com

This site works perfectly well on Safari. Any idea what could be causing this error?

Comment: 403: forbidden. Typically an auth failure. Try clearing your caches and cookies and trying again (or log out and in if you are able to).

Comment: Thanks @Bob. I have deleted all cookies and cache from *.whatsapp.com domain in Chrome, and reload. In the inspector, I can see new files downloaded to the App Cache. Still get the same websocket error after that

Comment: Could you double-check your proxy settings? Both system-wide and in Chrome. Also, make sure you're visiting the same subdomain in both browsers - apparently some-origin could potentially be an issue with websockets.

Comment: No answer, can't comment. Same on Window Chrome Canary (Dev Version 46.0.2467.2), but not on the default one 44.0.2403.107. On sunday or monday Google released a chrome version with multiple bugs and fixed some of it 1-2 days later. I believe the major bug (always send "https=1") is the problem. BTW: A non fixed minor bug (not communicated by Google) on the same release is the deny of some encoded Unicode chars in URLs. It's fun to change a complete framework, because the Chrome breaks the standard over the weekend. :(

Comment: Double check that you are not using a CORS overrider of some sorts

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in some recent Chrome canaray and dev versions. It is already fixed in canary and will be fixed in the next dev version.
It is not your fault, you can only wait and user a different browser or use a different Chrome release channel until the next dev version is released.

Source: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=514067

Update: With the just released update to 46.0.2471.2 dev-m on the dev channel, the issue is fixed :)